# How can I parallelize a pipeline of generators/iterators in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, parallel-processing, pipeline

Suppose I have some Python code like the following:

```
input = open("input.txt")
x = (process_line(line) for line in input)
y = (process_item(item) for item in x)
z = (generate_output_line(item) + "\n" for item in y)
output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.writelines(z)
```

This code reads each line from the input file, runs it through several functions, and writes the output to the output file. Now *I* know that the functions `process_line`, `process_item`, and `generate_output_line` will never interfere with each other, and let's assume that the input and output files are on separate disks, so that reading and writing will not interfere with each other.

But Python probably doesn't know any of this. My understanding is that Python will read one line, apply each function in turn, and write the result to the output, and then it will read the second line only *after* sending the first line to the output, so that the second line does not enter the pipeline until the first one has exited. Do I understand correctly how this program will flow? If this is how it works, is there any easy way to make it so that multiple lines can be in the pipeline at once, so that the program is reading, writing, and processing each step in parallel?

Comment: I think you'd need to add multithreading for this, so I'd say no - you don't have multithreading in CPython and in other implementations, it's propably not worth having a hundred lines instead of five.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't really parallelize reading from or writing to files; these will be your bottleneck, ultimately. Are you *sure* your bottleneck here is CPU, and not I/O?

Since your processing contains no dependencies (according to you), it's trivially simple to use [Python's multiprocessing.Pool class](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

There are a couple ways to write this, but the easier w.r.t. debugging is to find independent critical paths (slowest part of the code), which we will make run parallel. Let's presume it's process_item.

…And that's it, actually. Code:

```
import multiprocessing.Pool

p = multiprocessing.Pool() # use all available CPUs

input = open("input.txt")
x = (process_line(line) for line in input)
y = p.imap(process_item, x)
z = (generate_output_line(item) + "\n" for item in y)
output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.writelines(z)
```

I haven't tested it, but this is the basic idea. Pool's imap method makes sure results are returned in the right order.

Comment: I'm running this on a server with *really* fast I/O. It surprised me too that I/O wasn't the bottleneck. Also, I can read and write at the same time with little slowdown on either. Is there any reason I can't or shouldn't use `p.imap` on all three processing steps? I have 48 cores to play with, so if I can parallelize at all well, I might be able to make the I/O the slow step again.

Comment: 48 cores is… alot. So many that the locking/semaphore overhead from Python's multiprocessing module becomes significant. Maybe you should be looking at Hadoop instead?

Comment: To answer your question, it depends on your code. Guessing from what you've given, I'd probably combine all 3 functions into one (that takes line, and returns the output line) and pass that to imap.

Comment: Will there be less overhead if I don't care about preserving the order of lines?

Comment: If you don't care about the order and process_item, p.imap_unordered might be slightly faster (it will produce results in order of completion, so that you might start writing those lines to output.txt just a bit sooner)

Answer (score 1):

> is there any easy way to make it so that multiple lines can be in the pipeline at once

I wrote a library to do just this: https://github.com/michalc/threaded-buffered-pipeline, that iterates over each iterable in a separate thread.

So what was

```py
input = open("input.txt")

x = (process_line(line) for line in input)
y = (process_item(item) for item in x)
z = (generate_output_line(item) + "\n" for item in y)

output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.writelines(z)
```

becomes

```py
from threaded_buffered_pipeline import buffered_pipeline

input = open("input.txt")

buffer_iterable = buffered_pipeline()
x = buffer_iterable((process_line(line) for line in input))
y = buffer_iterable((process_item(item) for item in x))
z = buffer_iterable((generate_output_line(item) + "\n" for item in y))

output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.writelines(z)
```

How much actual parallelism this adds depends on what's actually happening in each iterable, and how many CPU cores you have/how busy they are.

The classic example is the Python GIL: if each step is fairly CPU heavy, and just uses Python, then not much parallelism would be added, and this might not be faster than the serial version. On the other hand, if each is network IO heavy, then I think it's likely to be faster.