# Parallelize a sequence of generators

Tags: python, parallel-processing, stream, generator

Assume I have Python stream-processing code that looks like this:

```
def F1(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield f1(x)

def F2(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield f2(x)

def F3(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield f3(x)

def F4(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield f4(x)


for x in F4(F3(F2(F1(range(1000000))))):
    print(x)
```

This is roughly equivalent to `range 1000000 | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4` in Unix (assuming a `range` command), but in Unix each process in the pipe runs in parallel.

**Is there a simple way to parallelize the Python code?**

Comment: Note: I've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684992/how-can-i-parallelize-a-pipeline-of-generators-iterators-in-python, but my actual use case is a bit more complicated than a simple `map`: each of `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, and `F4` actually accumulate some state as they process values.

Comment: If anyone is interested in seeing the full code, it's on http://pit-claudel.fr/clement/blog/an-experimental-estimation-of-the-entropy-of-english-in-50-lines-of-python-code/

Comment: If they accumulate state, how do you guarantee it's even possible to parallelize them?

Comment: Because the state that they accumulate is local to each function (not shared between the functions)

Comment: An excellent question. Unfortunately Python is probably not the correct answer.

Comment: It is probably possible to parallelize the operation, but probably not *simply* (i.e., without refactoring the code a good deal).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, that's also the conclusion that I had come to... Can you suggest another language? I find this "sequence of generators"/piping idea very pretty, and it's disappointing that although Python let's you express the sequence of stream manipulations very nicely, the same constructs don't allow for easy parallelization :/

Comment: What about using the multi-process implementation? There's also an actor implementation built atop this which probably will solve this in a more elegant manner without having to force you to write the "hacks" multi-process needs.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/aht/stream.py can do it.  Documentation for it is at http://www.trinhhaianh.com/stream.py.  Two languages with built-in support for stream parallelization are Scala and Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You need pipes and blackmagic, Python has both.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def F1(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield str(x)+'a'

def F2(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield x+'b'

def F3(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield x+'c'

def F4(stream):
    for x in stream:
        yield x+'d'



class PIPE_EOF:
    pass

class IterableConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        self.pipe = pipe

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            ret = self.pipe.recv()
            if ret == PIPE_EOF:
                raise StopIteration
            return ret
        except EOFError:
            raise StopIteration

    def next(self):
        return self.__next__()


def parallel_generator_chain(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'data' in kwargs:
        data = kwargs['data']
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Missing "data" argument.')

    def decorator(func, _input, _output):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for item in func(_input):
                _output.send(item)
            _output.send(PIPE_EOF)
        return wrapper

    for func in args:
        in_end, out_end = Pipe(duplex = False)
        in_end = IterableConnection(in_end)
        func = decorator(func, data, out_end)
        p = Process(target = func)
        p.start()
        data = in_end

    for output in data:
        yield output



if 'xrange' not in globals():
    xrange = range


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in parallel_generator_chain(xrange, F1, F2, F3, F4, data=100000000):
        print(x)

#for x in F4(F3(F2(F1(range(1000000))))):
#    print(x)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for your reply! I've been trying to get your code to work, but I didn't manage (Python 3.3). Your `decorator` function doesn't return anything, and the code doesn't produce any output at all; so I added a return to the decorator, but I get `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed`. Did the code run properly for you? Thanks again.

Comment: You are right. I wrote it much like a proof of concept than a working code, so I didn't test it. However I've edited my post with a working version. It should work with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I still get the "_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed" thingy on Windows; will try it on Unix and keep you posted.

Comment: I cannot try it on Windows, but are you running _exactly_ my code?

Comment: Yup, no modifications at all.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Pickle is evil!

Comment: Pickle, actually, is used by python's `multiprocess` itself. And it isn't that evil if you know what you are doing.